# [Sencha+phonegap+InAppBrowser]I can't catch events from inAppBrowser window

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, inappbrowser

I have a sencha app and launch in Android with phonegap. In my controller config.js I do window.open() when the user push a button and I add the Event Listener for 'loadstop' but I don't receive the event never.

```
onDeviceReady: function(){
  var manual = window.open('resources/manual/manual.html', '_blank', 'location=no');
  manual.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('start'); });
},

goToManual: function () {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

thanks for the help and sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are using the default JS method `window.open`. Since *sencha* mixes up things
in that case, I don't think you can add listeners or make changes if you are working on a mobile device.

So use this instead to make sure your call uses Cordova plugin:

```
var manual = null;
Cordova.exec(manual = window.open('resources/manual/manual.html', '_blank', 'location=no'));
```

The app crashes for me a few seconds after opening the page though.